# Updating d3 elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to udpate this bubblechart base on my search input in an input bar. Right now, I put all the d3 code in a Bubble.js, and then in my app.js, I have a searchinput element that will filter my data to be displayed, and then in my Bubble's state, I set its data equal to the filtered data (named RoadmapData). However, my bubble chart is not updating. **Actually, each time I type something in, another bubble chart renders, so if I type in 3 letters there are three same and unfiltered bubble charts**.

Here is my code right now:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";

class Bubble extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataset: { children: this.props.RoadmapData }
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    var diameter = 600;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var bubble = d3
  .pack(this.state.dataset)
  .size([diameter, diameter])
  .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .attr("class", "bubble");

var nodes = d3.hierarchy(this.state.dataset).sum(function(d) {
  return d.Count;
});

var node = svg
  .selectAll(".node")
  .data(bubble(nodes).descendants())
  .enter()
  .filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
  })
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
node.append("title").text(function(d) {
  return d.Name + ": " + d.Count;
});

node
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  });

node
  .append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".2em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.Name.substring(0, d.r / 3);
  })
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", function(d) {
    return d.r / 5;
  })
  .attr("fill", "white");

node
  .append("text")
  .attr("dy", "1.3em")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.data.Count;
  })
  .attr("font-family", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT")
  .attr("font-size", function(d) {
    return d.r / 5;
  })
  .attr("fill", "white");
  }

  render() {
return <div>{this.node}</div>;
  }
}

export default Bubble;
```

I am a beginner in d3, but I feel like the problem is either that I am using lifecycle methods wrong ( I used componentWillReceiveProps here, when I used componentMount() and typed in my search bar, nothing changed. Or maybe I shouldn't return this.node? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that each time your component is re-rendered, the `componentWillReceiveProps` function is creating a new instance of the visualization and adding it to the `<div>` node created by React, via the calls to `node.append`. You can avoid this by removing the previously created instances via the [d3 `remove()` function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_remove).

If you're willing to introduce another library, there's one called [React Faux Dom](https://github.com/Olical/react-faux-dom) that would allow you to avoid all the React lifecycle stuff and just do everything in the `render()` function as normal. It may simplify things a little.

You also mention that the chart is unfiltered every time - this is because you only assign the data prop to `state` in the constructor - this only runs once when your component is first created. In this case, it looks like you can safely remove this and read the data from `this.props.RoadmapData` every time (It doesn't appear that you are making any changes to the state inside the component).

You'd just need to add a line at the beginning of `render()` to get the data into the right format for d3, something like:

`var roadmapDataForD3 = { children: this.props.RoadmapData };`

Comment: Hey, thank you so much, I think this is indeed the right answer. But I think if I just do this.props.RoadmapData, it doesn't work because I am missing the "children" part, do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: You can build the object you need with `children` at the beginning of the `render()` function, and just keep passing that new variable into the d3 commands. That should do it. (Something like `var roadmapDataForD3 = { children: this.props.RoadmapData };`)