# How to remove the previous instance from ReactJS through D3?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I would like to draw new treemap every time the data (data is generated based on the user interaction such as button clicks) is changed. At the moment every time the data is changed a new treemap is created but it is drawn on top of the previous treemap - meaning I can see both treemaps on the screen. Somehow the previous instance is not removed.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54120318/updating-d3-elements-in-react) and [this](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_remove), and applied `remove()` function to remove the previous instance via d3. However, it does not work. I may be incorrectly used the `remove` function in the life cycle.

`d3.select("treemap").remove();` is used in the second `useEffect` method.

```
export function Treemap({ width, height, data }) {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3
      .select(ref.current)
      .attr("id", "treemap")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    //THIS IS WHERE I USE REMOVE FUNCTION;
    d3.select("treemap").remove();
    draw();
  }, [data]);

  const draw = () => {
    const svg = d3.select(ref.current);

    // Give the data to this cluster layout:
    var root = d3.hierarchy(data).sum(function (d) {
      return d.value;
    });

    // initialize treemap
    d3
      .treemap()
      .size([width, height])
      .paddingTop(28)
      .paddingLeft(0)
      .paddingRight(0)
      .paddingBottom(7)
      .paddingInner(3)(root);

    const color = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(["Diary", "Sweetner", "Fruit"])
      .range(["#8FD175", "#402D54", "#E67E22"]);

    const opacity = d3.scaleLinear().domain([10, 30]).range([0.5, 1]);

    // Select the nodes
    var nodes = svg.selectAll("rect").data(root.leaves());

    // draw rectangles
    nodes
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.x0;
      })
      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.y0;
      })
      .attr("width", function (d) {
        return d.x1 - d.x0;
      })
      .attr("height", function (d) {
        return d.y1 - d.y0;
      })
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .style("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.parent.data.name);
      })
      .style("opacity", function (d) {
        return opacity(d.data.value);
      });

    nodes.exit().remove();

    // select node titles
    var nodeText = svg.selectAll("text").data(root.leaves());

    // add the text
    nodeText
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.x0 + 5;
      }) // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.y0 + 20;
      }) // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.name;
      })
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill", "white");

    // select node titles
    var nodeVals = svg.selectAll("vals").data(root.leaves());

    // add the values
    nodeVals
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.x0 + 5;
      }) // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.y0 + 35;
      }) // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.value;
      })
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "white");

    // add the parent node titles
    svg
      .selectAll("titles")
      .data(
        root.descendants().filter(function (d) {
          return d.depth == 1;
        })
      )
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", function (d) {
        return d.x0;
      })
      .attr("y", function (d) {
        return d.y0 + 21;
      })
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.data.name;
      })
      .attr("font-size", "19px")
      .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.data.name);
      });

  };

  return (
    <div className="chart">
      <svg ref={ref}></svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, with d3, you never remove the already drawn nodes. It's much cheaper (computationally) and easier to just repurpose them!

If you really want to remove all nodes, `d3.select("treemap")` doesn't do anything, because "treemap" is not a valid selector. Try `#treemap` instead.

Or, if you want to repurpose the already drawn bits, consider the following:

```js
function Treemap({
  width,
  height
}) {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(`
    {
      "name": "Fruit",
      "children": [
        { "name": "Apples", "value": 1 },
        { "name": "Oranges", "value": 1 },
        { "name": "Bananas", "value": 1 }
      ]
    }
  `);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const svg = d3
      .select(ref.current)
      .attr("id", "treemap")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    draw();
  }, [data]);

  const draw = () => {
    const svg = d3.select(ref.current);

    let parsedData
    try {
      parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return;
    }

    // Give the data to this cluster layout:
    var root = d3.hierarchy(parsedData).sum(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });

    // initialize treemap
    d3
      .treemap()
      .size([width, height])
      .paddingTop(28)
      .paddingLeft(0)
      .paddingRight(0)
      .paddingBottom(7)
      .paddingInner(3)(root);

    const color = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(["Diary", "Sweetner", "Fruit"])
      .range(["#8FD175", "#402D54", "#E67E22"]);

    const opacity = d3.scaleLinear().domain([10, 30]).range([0.5, 1]);

    // Select the nodes
    var nodes = svg.selectAll("rect").data(root.leaves());

    // draw rectangles
    var newNodes = nodes
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .style("stroke", "black");

    nodes.merge(newNodes)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x0;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y0;
      })
      .attr("width", function(d) {
        return d.x1 - d.x0;
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return d.y1 - d.y0;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.parent.data.name);
      })
      .style("opacity", function(d) {
        return opacity(d.data.value);
      });

    nodes.exit().remove();

    // select node titles
    var nodeVals = svg.selectAll(".val").data(root.leaves());
    nodeVals.exit().remove();

    // add the values
    var newNodeVals = nodeVals
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .classed("val", true)
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "white");

    nodeVals.merge(newNodeVals)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x0 + 5;
      }) // +10 to adjust position (more right)
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y0 + 35;
      }) // +20 to adjust position (lower)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.value;
      });

    // add the parent node titles
    var titles = svg
      .selectAll(".title")
      .data(
        root.descendants().filter(function(d) {
          return d.depth == 1;
        })
      );

    titles.exit().remove();
    var newTitles = titles
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .classed("title", true)
      .attr("font-size", "19px");

    titles.merge(newTitles)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x0 + 5;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y0 + 21;
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name;
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.data.name);
      });
  };

  return ( <
    div className = "chart" >
    <
    textarea onChange = {
      (el) => setData(el.target.value)
    }
    value = {
      data
    }
    rows = "20"
    cols = "50" / >
    <
    svg ref = {
      ref
    } > < /svg> <
    /div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Treemap width = "600"
  height = "300" / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In any case, all your selectors were missing the `.`-class prefix. I'd recommend to read up on selectors, and on the `enter(), exit(), merge()` lifecycle.

Comment: I've updated the answer to a runnable snippet. You can now change the data directly and see it update. You didn't remove the old texts, but the nodes were removed. `titles.exit().remove()` did the trick. I also removed `nodeText`, because it was almost the same as `titles`, but then white.

Comment: Repurposing solution works fine if the data sizes are the same through out interactions. However, if I have different data sizes, I still see both drawn (previous & current) components on the screen. Consider the following datasets `previousdDataset = {id:"yellow",children:[{..},{...},{...},{...}]}` and  `currentDataset = {id:"green",children:[{..},{...}]}`

Comment: Consider the updated answer, and remove/add a child in the text area